# Recommended Calculation Weightings for ASP.net PasswordStrength Extender

Tags: asp.net, passwords, extender

I've been fiddling around with this control and I think I have a decent set of weightings. I'm looking to see if others think this is a good combination.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/passwordstrength/passwordstrength.aspx

I'm looking at 30;15;30;25

Where:
                      A = length weighting, 
                      B = numeric weighting, 
                      C = casing weighting, 
                      D = symbol weighting.

This gives "weak" for input like "password", "12345678" and "abcd1234".

Also, if anyone has advice on how to test this control outside of web container to see how it rates a password that would be great.

Thanks!